# opening multiple xml files as separate sheets in single excel workbook

Tags: xml, excel, vba, openxml

I have a PHP/MySQL program that generates a large excel workbook to make distributing it easier. i had been outputting one large xml file from PHP with multiple worksheets within one workbook. But the file has gotten unwieldy at over 1 mb in size in addition to being very hard to debug whenever there's a problem in the xml.

I am now outputting each worksheet as a separate file and reading them in separately using OpenXML. It allows me to debug each sheet and I only have to update the sheets that change. I read the xml into a temporary workbook using openxml, then copy the sheet to the master workbook. However, when openxml runs, it tries to resolve all references to other sheets. I say 'cancel' and let it run. But the cells with references to other sheets have #REF! in them. If I put the cursor in the formula and hit return, it resolves correctly. But I can't do that individually on every of thousands of formulas with references to other sheets.

Is there a way to read an xml file right into the existing master workbook?

Is there a way to have excel re-evaluate all formulas as if I clicked on it and hit enter?

Peter